# gulp server not running on any port

Tags: gulp

Hey guys i am new to angularJs so i am learning. i have used xampp before on port 8080 and now when i set up a gulp server it says that it started successfully but nothing appeared on browser. tried to change port but didnt work. what did i do wrong? here is my gulpfile.js

```
 var gulp   = require('gulp'),
    connect = require('gulp-connect'),
    historyApiFallback = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

    //Development Web Server
gulp.task('server', function(){
    connect.server({
        root: './app',
        hostname: 'localhost',
        port: 2020,
        liverload: true,
        middleware: function(connect, opt){
            return [ historyApiFallback ];
        }

    });

    });


var stylus = require('gulp-stylus'),
    nib    = require('nib');


//Preprocess Stylus files to CSS and reload changes
gulp.task('css', function(){
    gulp.src('./app/stylesheets/main.styl')
       .pipe(stylus({use: nib()}))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/stylesheets'))
       .pipe(connect.reload());
});



//Reload the browser on HTML changes
gulp.task('html', function(){
    gulp.src('./app/**/*.html')
       .pipe(connect.reload());
});





//watch code changes and to run related tasks
gulp.task('watch' , function(){
    gulp.watch(['./app/**/*.html'],['html']);
    gulp.watch(['./app/stylesheets/**/*.styl'],['css']);

});

gulp.task('default', ['server', 'watch']);
```

Comment: liverload should be livereload? What does the browser say when you navigate to localhost:2020?

Comment: hey thanks for the reply it just keep refreshing doesn't do anything really


however after fixing the typo livereload started on its own port but localhost still not doing anything

Comment: Have you ensured port 2020 is available? It might be something else on your system is using port 2020 and is preventing you from accessing your gulp server

Comment: well yes i have tried lots of different ports but the result is the same for a strange reason.